# .NET Regular Expression for Regular Expression Parsing

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to return matches from a regular expression string. The regex string is:

```
(?<TICKER>[A-Z]+)(?<SPACE>\\s)(?<MONTH_ALPHA_ABBREV>Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)(?<SPACE>\\s)(?<DAY>\\d+)(?<SPACE>\\s)(?<YEAR_LONG>[2][0][0-9][0-9])(?<SPACE>\\s)(?<STRIKE_DOLLAR>\\d+(?=[.]))[.](?<STRIKE_DECIMAL>(?<=[.])\\d+)(?<SPACE>\\s)(?<PUTCALL_LONG>Call|Put)
```

And I want to get matches for all of the group names and all of the items within square brackets (including the square brackets) outside of open and closed parenthesis. I have this regex:

```
((?<=[<])([A-Z]|[_])+(?=[>]))|(\\[.\\])
```

But this returns square bracket items within the parenthesis. To be more specific these are the matches I want from the regex at the top (keep in mind this needs to be flexible for any regex):

```
TICKER
SPACE
MONTH_ALPHA_ABBREV
SPACE
DAY
SPACE
YEAR_LONG
SPACE
STRIKE_DOLLAR
[.]
STRIKE_DECIMAL
SPACE
PUTCALL_LONG
```

Comment: @Chris: FYI, regular expressions are not part of the C# language - they're part of the .NET Framework.

Comment: "meta regex" ! man, you're in for a headache...

Comment: Did it occur to you that regular expressions *describe* a regular language? Which means they can't be *themselves* a regular language. Parsing regular expressions with regular expressions is therefore not possible.

Comment: @Tomalak: Ok . . . then pretend that string is not a regular expression and voila, now we can run a regular expression on it, but I very much appreciate your pompous response.

Comment: @Tomalak: that reasoning is incorrect. “Real” regular expressions *are* in fact regular, they form a regular language. Just as contex-free grammars can be described in a context free language (look at the Wikipedia article for the “Backus–Naur Form” to see a formal definition *in* BNF). The reason why “colloquial” regular expressions are no longer regular is because of nested grouping parentheses (although even these could be expressed using modern regexps which include non-regular stack extensions).

Comment: @Chris: It’s not really such a pompous response. For example, how do you intend to deal with nested parentheses in that expression? The accepted answer can’t do this.

Comment: @Red: You are right. I was hesitant of adding the hint to nested groups to make my point valid. I should have done so. @Chris I didn't mean to be offensive, sorry for that. People also pretend HTML is a string and run regexes on it all the time. I guess I got a little thin-skinned on the topic of applying regex inappropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
((?<=[<])([A-Z]|[_])+(?=[>]))|(?<!\([^\)]*)\[[^\]]+\]
```

Also, use the `@""` notation so you don't have to escape the backslashes (as you did in your example code).  This puppy's illegible enough.

Answer (score 0):

When you match your regex you can set the options to include `RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture` which will only capture named groups normally everything inside parentheses is captured. Then you can name all your capture groups using this format `(?<captureGroupName>[insertRegExHere])`.  This allows you to capture whatever you like and use sensible names.